# "TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties" in AS3

Tags: flash, jquery-animate, adobe, cc

I'm creating an Android game using Adobe Animate CC for our thesis, and every time I test my work, at first, it works fine, but when I go to the main game, there's an error appears:

```
Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties at RECOVER_RECOVER_dmthesis_demo_ver__paggumanarename_Scene14_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[RECOVER_RECOVER_dmthesis_demo_ver__paggumanarename_Scene14_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:160]
```

And this is my code (including commented code):

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.utils.Timer;


gril.gotoAndStop('a');


var gril:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
var linya:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
var timer:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
var scorer:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
var xDistance:Number 
var yDistance:Number
var fl_SecondsToCountDown:Number = 5;
var fl_CountDownTimerInstance:Timer = new Timer(1000, fl_SecondsToCountDown);
var vx:Number = 5; 
var vy:Number = 5;
var bg:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
var bg2:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
var qnaWin:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
var corekWin:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
var maliWin:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
var gameOverWin:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
//var btnPause:Button = new Button;
//var forward:Button = new Button;


bg.visible = true;
bg2.visible = false;
gril.visible = true;
linya.visible = true;
btnPause.visible = true;
pauseWin.visible = false;
qnaWin.visible = false;
corekWin.visible = false;
maliWin.visible = false;
scorer.visible = false;
timer.visible = false;
forward.visible = true;
gameOverWin.visible = false;


//var rightpressed:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
//var leftPressed:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
//var linkspeed:Number = 10;
//var contactApak: Boolean =false;


/*else if(keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
leftpressed = true;
}*/


//forward.enabled = true;
forward.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myClickReaction); 
// speeds ALONG NYPOTENUSE
function myClickReaction (e:MouseEvent):void {  
     vx = mouseX - gril.x;
     vy = mouseY - gril.y; 
     addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame); 
  gril.x+=10;
     gril.gotoAndStop('i');
}
/*stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, keyDownHandler);
function keyDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
if(event == Keyboard.RIGHT){
rightpressed = true;
  }
}*/



function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void { 
     //mc increments by 5 until it reaches mouse - mc (ie the distance) 
     gril.x += vx; 
     gril.y += vy; 
     xDistance = Math.abs(mouseX - gril.x); 
     yDistance = Math.abs(mouseY - gril.y); 
     trace (xDistance) 
     if (xDistance == 0 ) { 
          removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame); 
     } 
}
/*forward.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, lakad);
function lakad(event:MouseEvent):void{
if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
rightpressed = false;
gril.gotoAndStop('a');
}
}*/
/*else if(keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
leftpressed = false;
mcgril.gotoAndStop("Stand Left Frame");
}*/




/*stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoopi);
forward.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gameLoopi);
function gameLoopi(e:Event):void{
gril.x+=10;
gril.gotoAndStop('i');
}*/
/*else if(leftpressed){
linkMC.x-=linkspeed;
linkMC.gotoAndStop("Walk Left Frame);
}*/
if(linya.hitTestObject(gril)){
  qnaWin.visible = true;
}
/*if(apak.hitTestPoint(mcgril.x,mcgril.y+15,true)){
  contactApak=true;
}
else{
  contactApak=false;
}}*/

//btnPause.enabled = true;
btnPause.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pois);

function pois(event:MouseEvent):void{
  stage.frameRate = 0;
  bg.visible = true;
  bg2.visible = false;
  gril.visible = false;
  linya.visible = false;
  btnPause.visible = false;
  pauseWin.visible = true;
  qnaWin.visible = false;
  corekWin.visible = false;
  maliWin.visible = false;
  scorer.visible = false;
  timer.visible = false;
  forward.visible = false;
  gameOverWin.visible = false;
}


pauseWin.btnResume.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gorau);


function gorau(event:MouseEvent):void{
  bg.visible = true;
  bg2.visible = false;
  gril.visible = true;
  linya.visible = true;
  btnPause.visible = true;
  pauseWin.visible = false;
  qnaWin.visible = false;
  corekWin.visible = false;
  maliWin.visible = false;
  scorer.visible = false;
  timer.visible = false;
  forward.visible = true;
  gameOverWin.visible = false;
}


pauseWin.btnQtm.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kweet);


function kweet(event:MouseEvent):void{
  gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 1");
}


/*var objectoriginalX:Number;
var objectoriginalY:Number;*/


**corekWin.btnGo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gorabelx);**//this is in the line 160, the main problem


function gorabelx(event:MouseEvent):void{
  bg2.visible = true;
  bg.visible = false;
  //mcbackground.room.pinto(scaleY =-1);
  }

//timer.timee.text=fl_SecondsToCountDown.toString();
fl_CountDownTimerInstance.start();


fl_CountDownTimerInstance.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, foo);


function foo(event:TimerEvent):void
{
  fl_SecondsToCountDown--;
  timer.timee.text=fl_SecondsToCountDown.toString();
  trace(fl_SecondsToCountDown + " seconds");
  if(fl_SecondsToCountDown == 0){
  gameOverWin.visible = true;
  }
}


gameOverWin.btnTry.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tryk);


function tryk(event:MouseEvent):void{
  bg.visible = true;
  bg2.visible = false;
  gril.visible = true;
  linya.visible = true;
  btnPause.visible = true;
  pauseWin.visible = false;
  qnaWin.visible = false;
  corekWin.visible = false;
  maliWin.visible = false;
  scorer.visible = false;
  timer.visible = false;
  forward.visible = true;
  gameOverWin.visible = false;
}
```

Oops! My code is too long. I checked my code in many times and nothing is wrong, I also debug it and this kind of error still appears. I already declare the corekWin (the movieclip) but the btnGo (the another movieclip which enables to click) inside of corekWin doesn't need to declare it, right? Because the corekWin is already declared.

I'm trying to fix that error, and unfortunately, it fails. I have double-checked it. What do you think is the problem with this code?

Comment: Are you using two .fla files?
It seems that you have a problem in RECOVER_RECOVER_dmthesis_demo_ver__paggumanarename_Scene14_fla and in OVER_RECOVER_dmthesis_demo_ver__paggumanarename_Scene14_fla
It's difficult to figure me what's the issue since you use a lot of scenes.
The code is on te1st frame?
The error message says that you have a problem on scene 14.
I cannot figure me out what happens on scene 14 and what is your code on this scene.
To pause an animation you should use a stop() an start() method and there's no need to set the framerate @ 0
You create a lot of MC and not addChild

Comment: This is unclear and confusing @cjoyy27

Comment: @tatactic No. I'm using only one .fla file (this project RECOVER_RECOVER_dmthesis_demo_ver__paggumanarename_Scene14.f‌​la). I just copied from output and I didn't remove the space between REC and OVER (that supposedly RECOVER.. sorry for this). I'm using lot of scenes. I'm using "Test Scene" to make sure that the code that I created is working or not. Even I test the whole project, the same error appears.

Comment: `corekWin.btnGo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gorabelx);` This is in the line 160, the main error.

Comment: Alright, but the lines are not displayed and I have not time enough to count to the line 160 ;)
Mark the line in bold please.
However I think this question is a little unclear, but I will not "downvote" it. ;)
Sincerely.
Nicolas

Comment: I already have a comment there "this is in the line 160, the main problem" if you notice that. Thanks btw.

Comment: If you're not coding one one frame and jump from frame to frame or scene to scene, the code You provided is totally unclear.
It's difficult to find the reason of your issue quickly.
Please think 
1° That the person who will answer Your question has not a lot of time.
2° If He/She have to rewrite all your .fla without more details it's difficult to figure what's the issue, this is a long way to go.
@VCOne is often right and You have to consider his answer!
His answer is short and clear. I suppose that he is right.

Comment: So try to work on his answer... This is the best way to solve your issue I think.

Best regards.

Comment: Helpful tip: questions featuring "ASAP" and "I really need an answer" and [other forms of hurrying volunteers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) are often downvoted here. Please don't add these to your questions, thanks!

Comment: @halfer Ok. I got it. Tbh I dunno what is do's and don't here since I'm a newbie here. Thanks for your reminder. :)

Comment: @cjoyy27: thanks for being willing to listen, though this is not specific to _Stack Overflow_. My philosophical observation is that no-one asks volunteers for "ASAP", in real life, anywhere in the world, so I am left wondering why it is different on the internet.

Comment: @halfer You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding this line :

```
var corekWin:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
```

You just created a new blank (**empty**) MovieClip object with reference name `corekWin`, since you never did a  `corekWin.addChild(btnGo);` you cannot say ;

```
corekWin.btnGo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gorabelx);
```

It fails because `corekWin` is an empty `new Movieclip`, it does not contain any `btnGo` object.

**possible solution** :

If `corekWin` is a MovieClip in your **Library** (ctrl+L), then you should give it a **linkage** name (right-lick and go to *Properties* and give a linkage name, for example call it `mc_corekWin`).

Now in your code you can instantiate that existing MovieClip instead of creating a new empty one... :

```
var corekWin : mc_corekWin = new mc_corekWin();
```

Before adjusting any visual aspects, add it to the stage via `stage.addChild(corekWin);` then later you can do `corekWin.visible` or `corekWin.alpha` and so on.

**Edit** :

If your MC is already placed on the stage (at runtime) then you don't need to create a `new Movieclip`(or even a `new mc_corekWin`) variable. Simply reference the MC by the **instance** name you gave it.

- To undo the **linkage** just go back to the MC's properties in **Library** and un-tick that *"Export for Actionscript"* box.
- To add an **instance** name, click on the MC (click it on stage, not Library) and open **Properties** tab (ctrl+F3) and you'll see a section ready for your preferred name. The name you type (and press Enter to update) will be used in code.

Basically if an MC `xyz` is already on stage you don't need `var xyz:MovieClip = new MovieClip;` (this will override the on-stage MC) to control it by code, just give it an instance name and then use the name to reference the MC in code.

Likely you don't need vars like `gril` and `linya` etc to be `new MovieClip`. Try un-commenting them (using `//`) and see if they now become "not visible".

Comment: Ok. I got it. Hmm.. how about the `btnGo` inside of `corekWin`? Will I still do the `addChild` thingy?

Comment: It works! No more error appears but I still have a problem. The other movieclips should be hidden (e.g. `corekWin.visible = false`) but in run time, they still show. But thanks @VC One!

Comment: _"The other movieclips should be hidden"_... I've added an update. Also I suspect your MCs are already on stage? It's confusing that you were making `new MovieClips` but I think you assume you must do that to control them? if already on-stage then just contrl in code via the MC's instance name (different thing to **linkage** name and infact you should disable the linkage in order to use **instance** name instead)

Comment: I got error 1009 before but when I declare `var xyz:MovieClip = new MovieClip();`, that error (1009) is gone but another error (1010) appears.

Comment: Is the 1010 error caused by the `corekWin.btnGo...etc` line? If yes, does the `corekWin` MC actually contain another MC inside it with `btnGo` as instance name? The MC you want to instance as `new` must have a linkage name (this now makes it a Class), so once you make a `var xyz : someClass = new someClass` you reference it by the `xyz` name but any other MC's contained inside (its children) can be accessed by their instance names. Also no need for `xyz.addChild(btnGo)` since its already inside MC's own timeline. You can use an MC as button by `someMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK etc`

Comment: PS: **try this** after doing a `var xyz:corekWin = new corekWin();` (where `corekWin` is the linkage name), now add it to the stage with `stage.addChild(xyz);` from there you can say `xyz.btnGo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gorabelx);`... If you still get an error 1010 that means `btnGo` is the issue. You can test that with a simple `xyz.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gorabelx);` (which should not cause the error)