# How to walk a game character using mouse event in Adobe Animate CC AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This question is related to my previous post, [“TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties” in AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40446100/typeerror-error-1010-a-term-is-undefined-and-has-no-properties-in-as3) because as I mentioned there, I'm creating an Android Game for our thesis. Now, I have a spritesheet of a character in the link: [sprite character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdGvC.png), I'm using this in the game. I'm researching on how to walk a character, I found one at a website, it actually works but unfortunately, it fails because the character didn't actually walk. I have no idea on what code will be place there. Either I will walk a character by clicking mouse or I will create a button then click on it to walk a character. What would be the code can I use for that? Any help will be appreciated.

P.S. In my previous post, I'm creating a code from timeline but now I transfer it to Actionscript file because of some errors.

EDIT:
Here's my code of the character:

```
forward.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ppap);
function ppap(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gril.x += mouseX;
    gril.y += mouseY;
    gril.gotoAndStop('i');
    gameloop();
}

function gameloop(): void {
    for (var o = 0; o > 5; o++) {
        if (linya.hitTestObject(gril)) {
            o++;
            gotoAndStop(2);
            scorer.visible = true;
            timer.visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And the line: `gril.gotoAndStop('a');` where the character is standing.

The `gril` is the instance name of a character. When it reaches to `linya`, the question will appear. Thanks!

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: I will edit my question.

Comment: @NealDavis Here's my code above.

Comment: "*I'm creating an Android Game for our thesis*" so you are basically writing a thesis about something you have no idea about?

Comment: Try replacing mouseX with something like mouseX - gril.x

Comment: @NealDavis I'm trying for loop for the game, after the question of the game being answered, it'll proceed to the next stage which is the another background.

I will try it. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @null I mean, I know the flow of the game but I don't have an idea about to code the walking character thus this is actually my problem in many days, and I dunno how to solve it. 

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

Let's walk through your broken game loop

```
function gameloop(): void {
for (var o = 0; o > 5; o++) { //sets o to 0, loops as long as o > 5 (which it isn't, since we just set it to 0;
    if (linya.hitTestObject(gril)) {
        o++; //this also adds 1 to o
        gotoAndStop(2);
        scorer.visible = true;
        timer.visible = true;
    }
// if this part ever executed, it would add 1 to o
}
}
```

Do you see the problem? This for loop will not execute even once since 0 < 5

Instead it should be

```
function gameloop(): void {
for (var i  = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (linya.hitTestObject(gril)) {
        gotoAndStop(2);
        scorer.visible = true;
        timer.visible = true;
        break;
    }
}
}
```

So here we have a functional (but pointless) for loop. It will work, but the first time through the loop it is going to result in the exact same thing as the second and third and fourth and fifth because changing the variable value by 1 isn't actually changing anything at all. You just telling the program to check the collision state 5 times. Well it does this 5 times before *anything else* can change. It checks it 5 times every game loop. Well I promise you nothing is moving while that for loop is running so why check it 5 times? I suggest stepping back and getting some help from your teacher or something because this seems way off. Sorry.

Comment: @tatactic actually your `i==0` one would never execute either :)

Comment: @tatactic it should be `i >= 0`

Comment: true sorry for the mistake @NealDavis

Comment: Edited as an answer even this is not an answer...
@NealDavis I cannot edit the comment anymore :(

Comment: Anyway no feedback from @cjoyy27 :)

Comment: Next time, I will write the answers in Flash Buider just to see if my answer or comment is right ;)

Comment: Thanks again @NealDavis, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Right again @NealDavis and thank You for the comment!!!
I wrote my comment too quickly

Ascending loop from 0->4 (5 items):

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i < 5; i++){
    trace("ascending = " + i);
}
```

Output:

```
ascending = 0
ascending = 1
ascending = 2
ascending = 3
ascending = 4
```

Descending loop from 4->0 (5 items):

```
for (var j:int = 4; j>=0; j--){
// j must be an int in this case, second mistake!
    trace("descending = " + j)
};
```

Output:

```
descending = 4
descending = 3
descending = 2
descending = 1
descending = 0
```

My mistake. SRY

This is well explained in [Looping reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3_Flex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fcf.html)

And in [ActionScript 3 fundamentals: Loops reference](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/loops.html)

Shame on me!!! ;)

I'm a noob! :D

So I deleted my comment ;)

WOW, I'm so sorry about this mistake!!!

```
// You may also create Vectors to store the values.

var ascending:Vector.<uint> = new Vector.<uint>;
var descending:Vector.<uint> = new Vector.<uint>;

for (var k:uint = 0; k < 5; k++){
    ascending.push(k+1);
}
trace("ascending Vector.<uint> = " + ascending);
// Output : ascending Vector.<uint> = 1,2,3,4,5

for (var l:int = 4; l >= 0; l--){
    descending.push(l+1);
}
trace("descending Vector.<uint> = " + descending);
// Output : descending Vector.<uint> = 5,4,3,2,1
```

Or in an ascending loop :

```
trace("\nascending Vector.<uint> loop : ")
for(var m:String in ascending){
    trace(m + " = " + ascending[m]);
}
```

Output :

```
ascending Vector.<uint> loop : 
0 = 1
1 = 2
2 = 3
3 = 4
4 = 5
```

Or in a descending loop :

```
trace("descending Vector.<uint> loop : ")
for(var n:String in descending){
    trace(n + " = " + descending[n]);
}
```

Output:

```
descending Vector.<uint> loop : 
0 = 5
1 = 4
2 = 3
3 = 2
4 = 1
```

Comment: Is this a "possible" loop for the game? But, I wanna know the code for a character walking using mouse event. I already convert it into movieclip and separating the spritesheet of it using onion skin. It has only one direction, it walks thru the key and (in game loop) after grabbing a key, the question appears. And then, changes the background and repeat. Btw, the deadline of our thesis will be tomorrow until 7pm, PH time. :( Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: Ooooops, I will not find the time to give You this answer so quickly. SRY :(

Comment: Aww.. Hmm.. How about creating a game hint/clue? In a quiz question, there's a multiple choice, 4 choice. When quiz question is on-going, if the user doesn't know the answer, there's a clue, just to eliminate the two of it, and there's a number of clue. If a clue has been used, then the number of it will decrease by 1. If there's no more clue, and if the user answers in 3 consecutive correct answers, the clue will be increase by 1. :/

Comment: I'm just asking, because I need it to apply in my game (or maybe in other day because I want to finish only 50% of the system). If you have an idea about that then that's good but if none, it's ok. Btw, thanks again!